# JQuery UI Autocomplete on first and last name fields

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I would think someone else would have this problem but I cannot seem to find an answer anywhere. I would like to have 2 input fields, first and last name, with the same autocomplete source. When a user types in the first and last name fields, I want the autocomplete dropdown to filter by matching the first name to the first name field and the last name to the last name field.

My code currently, just implementing the autocomplete on both fields.

```
 $(function() {
   var names = ["John Smith", "Jimothy Doe", "Stuart Brown"];
   $( "#firstname" ).autocomplete({
   source: names
   });
   $( "#lastname" ).autocomplete({
   source: names
   });
 });


 <input type='text' id='firstname' />
 <input type='text' id='lastname' />
```

Typing a J in the first field will display John Smith and Jimothy Doe, but typing an S in the second field will only display John Smith, not Stuart Brown.

How it works currently: http://jsfiddle.net/HSYYz/1/

Comment: Carp. I guess I didn't choose the names wisely. I'll edit my names and add a link.

Comment: Ug, my bad. I misread your question. Bottom line though, you can't expect the autocomplete to know what part of the text you type in to search -- it uses the entire string. If you don't want it to you have to tell it to explicitly. You may want to look into splitting the input first.

Comment: @j08691 that's alright. i think i almost have it figured out. i'll post an answer when i get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to put functions in the source option and select event of the autocomplete widget.

```
$("#firstname, #lastname").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    term1 = $("#firstname").val();
    term2 = $("#lastname").val();
    names2 = new Array();
    i = 0;
    while (i < names.length) {
      namesSplit = names[i].split(RegExp(" +"));
      j = 2;
      while (j < namesSplit.length) {
        namesSplit[1] += " " + namesSplit[j];
        j++;
      }
      if (namesSplit[0].match(term1) && namesSplit[1].match(term2)) {
        names2.push(names[i]);
      }
      i++;
    }
    response(names2);
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    uiSplit = ui.split(RegExp(" +"));
    $("#firstname").val(uiSplit[0]);
    $("#lastname").val(uiSplit[1]);
  }
});
```

Sorry if the code is a little rough; I had to convert it from coffeescript.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but also needed support for middle name matches. 
I ended up making three functions and just changing the regex to match the different cases.

```
$( "#firstnameInput" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            //matches first letter of the whole name
            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
            response( $.grep( fullnavnArray, function( item ){
                return matcher.test( item );
            }) );
       }
    });

    $( "#middlenameInput" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            //matches "space" name "space" 
            var matcher = new RegExp( "\\s" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ) +"\\w+\\s", "i" );
            response( $.grep( fullnavnArray, function( item ){
                return matcher.test( item );
            }) );
       }
    });

    $( "#lastnameInput" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            //matches "space" name  
            var matcher = new RegExp( "\\s" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term )+"\\w+$", "i" );
            response( $.grep( fullnavnArray, function( item ){
                return matcher.test( item );
            }) );
       }
    });
```